# save createdAt as timestamp in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

this is user model

```js
    const mediaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            required: true,
            type: string,
        },
     
    },
     { timestamps: true }
    );
```

mongoose saves createdAt as `2022-10-21T14:31:09.650+00:00` in data base by default .

How can I force it to save it as `201546541658323` ?

Comment: Dates should be **never** stored as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects, e.i. `type: Date`. Storing date values as `Number` could be acceptable, however `Date` is the proper data type. You can compare `Date` values in the same way as you can compare numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not.

---

What you can do is disable Mongoose timestamps and create your own `createdAt` property that you will set to the format you want.

You can do it like this:

```js
const mediaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { required: true, type: string },
  createdAt: { type: Number, default: Date.now() }
});
```

In addition, you will have to create your logic for `updatedAt` property.

---

I don't know why you want to save it as a number, since you can easily convert the current format to the number with `Date.parse()` method:

```js
Date.parse("2022-10-21T14:31:09.650+00:00"); // 201546541658323
```

Comment: I want to save it as Number because it is much easier to compare

Comment: What do you mean? MongoDB has built in date filters. Can you give an example of your use case in the question?